# Div which contains text does not take the necessary width

Tags: html, css

Following my code:

```
<div style="min-width: 150px; max-width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid black;">test</div>
```

The 150px enough to contain all the text, instead the div takes the maximum size, in this case 200px. How to solve without float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A div automatically has a width of 100% since it is a block type element.  If you want it's width to scale with the content instead, try adding this attribute to the style tag: `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `display: inline-block;` on the `div`, you'll get it to be 152px (the min-width + border).

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vUhJe/).

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vUhJe/1/) with same margins as original post.

Comment: display: inline-block; and display: block; are the almost the same results as you were using float. He said he didn't want to use this (probably want to keep the margin)

Comment: If that's the case, setting `text-align: center;` on a containing `div`, and `text-align: left;` on the content `div` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `width: 150px` instead of `min-width`